# Webservers for development on OSX

Tags: mac-osx

Hey I want to build some web junk on OSX, I just want the software to be installed in a manageable package, like all the other good OSX stuff. preferably lighttpd but apache works too.

Comment: OSX already has Apache installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in Apache server on OS-X is probably your best bet. It comes with the PHP module pre-installed and with OS-X having ruby, perl, and python; there's no CGI-configuration necessary.

you'll find the configuration files here:

Apache:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

PHP:

```
/private/etc/php.ini
```

Answer (score 3):

Mac OS X comes with Apache pre-installed.  You do not need to install anything.

Here's a link to a tutorial:

http://shapeshed.com/journal/setting_up_local_websites_on_snow_leopard/

Comment: A decent guide, but I don't like how it abuses `.local` like that.

Comment: I agree. Technically speaking, *any* use of .local is abuse, because it is not reserved in [RFC 2606](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606). I would take it as a placeholder and use something sensible.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using MAMP on OSX which is pretty easy to set up and manage. You can use it for PHP/MySQL development served by Apache Web-server on your local machine.

http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html